# Error in : invalid program counter value: 0x00000000

Tags: arrays, string, integer, mips, mars-simulator

I have an assignment to take in an integer from the user, and output it as a string of chars (in MIPS).

I am using MARS, and am receiving the error:

> invalid program counter value: 0x00000000.

I have seen others ask this question, but the answer usually has to do with using `jal`, which I am using. As this is my first assembly language class, I am not so experienced with writing MIPS code, so I'm assuming there are simple errors that I am overlooking.

This is an assignment for school, so I'm not asking for the answer- I'm just looking for some direction so I can properly complete the problem. Also, please don't use any commands more complicated than what I have used here. (I have heavily commented the code, so I hope it'll be easy to look through.)
Thanks; I appreciate any input!

```
.data

InputPrompt: .asciiz "Enter an integer:"
Array: .space 16 #15 max space, at one byte each, plus a null terminator

.text

main: 
    la $a0, InputPrompt #prompt user to enter an integer
    li $v0, 4 #print out the prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5 #load the given input into register v0
    syscall

    move $a1, $v0 #move the input to register a1 to save it there(param for sub-routine)

    li $t1, 10 #load 10 into register t1 for division purposes

    la $a0, Array #store first spot of array


    jal getDigit

    jal printString #after all digits are converted and stored in the array, call the print sub-routine


getDigit: 
    addi $sp, $sp, -4   #make room on stack
    sw $ra, 0($sp)      #save $ra

loop:   beq $a1, $zero, return #if quotient has become 0, we are done
    div $a1, $t1 #divide number by 10
    mfhi $a2 #the modulus(remainder) of number/10 is here
    mflo $a3 #the quotient is here
    move $a1, $a3 #the new number is the quotient

    jal convertDigit #call the ConvertDigit sub-routine, with the number in the a2 parameter register

    j loop

    lw $ra, 0($sp) #restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 #restore stack pointer
    return: jr $ra

convertDigit:
    addi $sp, $sp, -8   #make room on stack
    sw $ra, 4($sp)      #save $ra
    addi $v1, $a2, 48 #convert to ascii 

    move $t3, $a0
    sb   $v1, 0($t3) #$t3 = Array[0] the first time, then gets incremented
    addi $t3, $t, 1 #increment index of array

    lw $ra, 0($sp) #restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 #restore stack pointer
    jr $ra #return to getDigit sub-routine

printString: 
    lb  $t1, Array($t2)  
    add $t2, $t2, 1
    bne $t1, $zero, printString
    sub $t2, $t2, 1

loop2:  lb $t0, 0($a0) # load a single character from the array into $t0
    li $v0, 11  
    syscall # print 
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # add 1 to the loop index 
    blt $t0, $t1, loop2 # continue if not at string length 

exit:   li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Mars has an "Undo the last step" button that allows you to step backwards from the crash.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified...I've stepped through the program already, and I've seen where it crashes. It crashes in the convertDigit sub-routine, when it tries to do jr $ra...But there is a jal to return to in the getDigit sub-routine, so I'm confused.

Comment: Also, I'm missing the number 3 after $t in the convertDigit sub-routine, but that isn't the issue...(It needs that $t3 to assemble correctly, and I do have that correct in my code.)

Comment: So your `$ra` is incorrect. Keep stepping backwards until you find where it gets its incorrect value.

Comment: Alright- So I can see that the value changes a few lines before, when I store a byte into the array. Why is this affecting the return address that I have stored on the stack?

Comment: That seems unlikely. Just let the program run until it crashes, then step backwards and watch for changes to the value of `$ra`.

Comment: I've found the problem- I was storing the second return value using an offset of 4, so it was storing to the same spot as the first return value. Now I just have a couple more things to work out, and then I have to include special cases on entering a negative number or a zero. Any insight on that? Can I just include special cases in the main function to take care of those? Thanks for the help so far, @Michael :)

Comment: My code now works almost perfectly for 0, positive numbers, and negative numbers! However, I've noticed that it crashes at the very beginning (trying to load the input into the register) if the user inputs 11 digits or more. Why is this? Myprofessor specified that we can assume the user won't enter more than 15 digits, but this is crashing at 11...

Comment: Also, if you're viewing this code, please note that I have made a LOT of changes to it to get it to work properly...Don't use the code above, because it won't work for many reasons.